# Video PHP scripts for every video site

Tags: embed

This is frustrating...

Right now I just have the following:

```
$regexes = array();
    //youtube regex, will go to matches[1]
    $regexes[] = '(?:https?:\/\/(?:(?:.+\.(?:youtube\.com|ytimg\.com))|(?:youtu\.be\/))(?:.*?)(?:\??vi?[\/\=]{1}|embed\/)([A-Za-z0-9\-_]{11}))';
    //vimeo regex, will go to matches[2]
    $regexes[] = '(?:https?:\/\/(?:.+\.)vimeo.com(?:\/video\/|(?:.+clip_id=))([a-z0-9-]+))';
```

That´s just Youtube and Vimeo. But what I want is Youtube, Vimeo, Dailymotion... and every other site in existence.

The idea is that I have a website that allows users to embed videos from other sites. Kinda like tumbler I guess. I have about a hundred sites in mind. But I don't know where to begin looking for a complete list of code for these sites.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to maintain a database with all video websites. I think you can get the URL content and search for the video tag. Unfortunately this will work only for sites which render the video using html5(not flash).

Comment: Yeah. I'm surprised that there isn't something already out there though. If nothing else news and media sites that embed content from multiple sites everyday should have this handy (like huffingtonpost.com or yahoo.com´s news section...) There should be some sort of repository for this infor somewhere...